# UITableView in a UIViewController linked to another ViewController (DetailController)

Tags: iphone, xcode, tableview, viewcontroller

I have an app on the store that uses a RootViewController linking to a UIViewController (DetailController) and I am working on a new app which basically requires the need for this same feature. But instead, my new app has a UITableView inside a UIViewController linked to a UIViewController. So I thought, i'd copy and paste my RootViewController code into this new UIViewController. So i've linked up the TableView, set delegate and datasource to self and the TableView shows the titles of the items (Hurrah) but when touched, doesn't go to the DetailController? I've used NSLog to determine what part isn't working and of course its the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method… and here is my code

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSDictionary *theItem = [items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    DetailController *nextController = [[DetailController alloc] initWithItem:theItem];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:nextController animated:YES];
    [nextController release];

}
```

The TableViewCell just highlights blue and doesn't link to DetailController.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you set up the navigation controller properly?

Comment: Yes completely all linked up. dataSource and delegate are both self

Comment: navigation controller doesnt need a datasource and delegate, is the view controller which has the table view inside a UINavigationController? put this in your didSelect method: `NSLog(@"Navigation Controller: %@", self.navigationController);`

Answer (score 0):

By "not working" do mean it's not being called, or that it's not pushing the view controller? If the first, then make sure the table view delegate is set correctly. If the second, make sure both nextController and self.navigationController are not nil.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response, I mean not pushing view controller. I haven't any code suggesting that they are nil?

Comment: You can add a break point and check, or use NSLog to print the value.